# UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean with name 'jdbcIngredientRepository':Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-repositories

I am referring book "Spring in Action 6th edition" , chapter 3 - Storing data using JDBC Template
I got the following issue

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcIngredientRepository' defined in file [D:\Java Projects\taco-cloud\target\classes\tacos\data\JdbcIngredientRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter

## **JdbcIngredientRepository**

```
package tacos.data;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import tacos.Ingredient;

@Repository
public class JdbcIngredientRepository implements IngredientRepository {
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  @Autowired
  public JdbcIngredientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterable<Ingredient> findAll() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select id, name, type from Ingredient",
        this::mapRowToIngredient);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Ingredient> findById(String id) {
    List<Ingredient> results = jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select id, name, type from Ingredient where id=?",
        this::mapRowToIngredient,
        id);
    return results.size() == 0 ?
            Optional.empty() :
            Optional.of(results.get(0));
  }

  @Override
  public Ingredient save(Ingredient ingredient) {
    jdbcTemplate.update(
        "insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values (?, ?, ?)",
        ingredient.getId(),
        ingredient.getName(),
        ingredient.getType().toString());
    return ingredient;
  }

  private Ingredient mapRowToIngredient(ResultSet row, int rowNum)
      throws SQLException {
    return new Ingredient(
        row.getString("id"),
        row.getString("name"),
        Ingredient.Type.valueOf(row.getString("type")));
  }
```

## **IngredientRepository**

```
package tacos.data;

import java.util.Optional;

import tacos.Ingredient;

public interface IngredientRepository {
    Iterable<Ingredient> findAll();
    Optional<Ingredient> findById(String id);
    Ingredient save(Ingredient ingredient);
```

i tried changing JDBC dependencies and also updating the Maven project

Answer (score 0):

IngredientRepository is an interface but does not extend a Spring Data interface which would make it a Spring bean.

It should extend for example CrudRepository:

```
public interface IngredientRepository extends CrudRepository<Ingredient, String>
```